# I can't get pass recaptcha with selenium infinitely stuck

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a auto form submitting project I tried selenium but I could fill the forms but when I click submit button a recaptcha being summoned, when I tried to bypass it with 2captcha but didn't work and after that I tried to do it manually but when I do it correctly it gets reseted can you help me with my code?

```
import time
import os
import requests
import random
import string
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import sys

def random_char(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))
mail = (random_char(7)+"@gmail.com")

driver = wd.Firefox(executable_path='C:\geckodriver.exe')
target_url = 'https://www.yemeksepeti.com/login/new?step=registration'
driver.get(target_url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
print(mail)
time.sleep(2)
email = str(mail)
time.sleep(2)
firstName = 'Mert'
time.sleep(2)
lastName = 'Demir'
time.sleep(2)
birthDate = '01-04-2001'
time.sleep(2)
password = 'AbcAbc123.*_123'
time.sleep(2)
emailPath = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="email"]')
time.sleep(2)
emailPath.send_keys(mail)
time.sleep(2)
firstNamePath = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="first_name"]')
time.sleep(2)
firstNamePath.send_keys(firstName)
time.sleep(2)
lastNamePath = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="last_name"]')
time.sleep(2)
lastNamePath.send_keys(lastName)
time.sleep(2)
birthDatePath = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="birthdate"]')
time.sleep(2)
birthDatePath.send_keys(birthDate)
time.sleep(2)
passwordPath = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="password"]')
time.sleep(2)
passwordPath.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)
Submit = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="login-page-react-root"]/main/div/form/div[8]/button')
Submit.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I mean it means the captcha is working, and considering recaptcha is made by google and does a lot more stuff than just check if you clicked the right boxes, I doubt it will be easy to bypass, good luck. And anyone that does know how to bypass it for sure won't share it publicly and for free.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for having a re-captcha is to stop bots (ie: selenium automation scripts) from interacting with the web page/form.
If you can bypass that this is a big red light for the application security. And is not recommended in standard QA practices.

What you need to do is to have your dev environment configured to be test friendly. There are multiple ways this can be achieved. From my personal experience :

1. Remove the captcha field for dev/test environment forms.
2. Have the developers setup a static captcha which always has **one known** captcha phrase
3. Test the feature with the captcha manually

I'm sure there are a lot of other ways to overcome this situation, but forcing the script to enter the real captcha is not the way to go